# : No IEdmType could be found for 'microsoft.management.services.api.groupPolicyObjectFile'

Tags: c#, odata, entity

I am creating an action that takes in an ODataActionParameter object. Where I create my model builder, I would like for the parameter it takes to receive an entity I created, however it throws ': No IEdmType could be found for 'microsoft.management.services.api.groupPolicyObjectFile'. When the parameter is a string type it works fine. Has anyone seen this IEdmType error before?

I've tried entityparameter, collectionparameter, and parameter for my model builder.

```
public void Configure(IContext context, ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        context.IfNullThrow(nameof(context));
        modelBuilder.IfNullThrow(nameof(context));

        modelBuilder.EntityType<GroupPolicyObjectFile>();
        modelBuilder.EntityType<GroupPolicyMigrationReport>();
        modelBuilder.EntityType<GroupPolicySettingMapping>();

        modelBuilder.EntityType<DeviceManagement>().Action("analyzeGroupPolicyObjectFile").Parameter<GroupPolicyObjectFile>("groupPolicyObjectFile");

    }
```

Here's the declaration of the entity I'd like to use:

```
[MinimumSupportedVersion(ServiceVersions.ExperimentalStart)]
[ODataDescription("The Group Policy Object file uploaded by admin.")]
[ODataCapabilities(supportsSkip: true, supportsTop: true)]
[GraphEntity(isMaster: true, AddressUrl = Constants.ServiceEndpoints.GPAnalyticsAdminService)]
[DataInventoryClass(Owner = Constants.Service.OwnerTeamAlias, DataStore = DataStore.DocDB, DataClassification = DataClassification.OII)]
public sealed class GroupPolicyObjectFile: GraphEntity
```

Action here:

```
[ODataRoute("analyzeGroupPolicyObjectFile")]     
[AuthorizeApplicationPermissionScopes(new string[] { DelegatedAppPermissionScopes.DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWriteAll }, new string[] { DelegatedAppPermissionScopes.DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWriteAll })]
[ODataParameterDescription("groupPolicyObjectFile", "Create group policy migration report")]
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AnalyzeGroupPolicyObjectFile(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `EntityParameter` instead of `Parameter` for entity parameters:

```
modelBuilder.EntityType<DeviceManagement>().Action("analyzeGroupPolicyObjectFile").EntityParameter<GroupPolicyObjectFile>("groupPolicyObjectFile");
```

If you need a collection of entities as a parameter use `CollectionEntityParameter`

See: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support